# how to implement voting functionality?

Tags: democracy

We wanted to survey about all the pallets that implement some sort of voting functionality (Like democracy pallet).

In our use case, an authorzed user will float a suggestion and Eligible voters will vote in favour of or against that suggestion. To vote, the voter will burn their tokens.

Can any one please provide a list of all such pallets that implements functionality similar to the above. Since, we wanted to study all such pallets and then will the one that best suits our requirements. I need list of all such pallets othar than the followig (Since, we already know about these pallets):

1. https://docs.rs/pallet-democracy/latest/pallet_democracy/
2. https://crates.io/crates/pallet-elections-phragmen
3. https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_treasury/pallet/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Some voting pallets that we are using at Webb are derived from ChainSafe/ChainBridge's pallet for voting on proposals. It's a simple threshold voting system. Our's works where only a single signature is needed to pass a proposal, where the signature is generated using a threshold-signature generation protocol using MPC.

- https://github.com/webb-tools/protocol-substrate/blob/main/pallets/signature-bridge/src/lib.rs
- https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-substrate/blob/main/chainbridge/src/lib.rs

We also use the same style of pallet in our system for having relayers vote on specific types of proposals that uses the simple threshold process described above without MPC. This is nearly identical to ChainSafe's implementation of the chainbridge pallet with different terminology and updates to certain data structures/events, etc.

- https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate/tree/master/pallets/dkg-proposals

Comment: Thank you very much @Drew. Let me check it in details.

Answer (score 0):

The list you mention are great examples to study. Regards to the pallet-elections-phragmen I want to share this two posts on the Polkadot Forum that are worth reding:

- [Thoughts on governance security and configs for parachains](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/thoughts-on-governance-security-and-configs-for-parachains/1166)
- [(Mis) Configuring pallet-elections-phragmen](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/mis-configuring-pallet-elections-phragmen/2502)

And just want to add one pallet into the list that might be useful for your research, from the Moombeam team: [The Conviction Voting Pallet](https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/pallets-precompiles/pallets/conviction-voting/). See the code [here](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/master/precompiles/conviction-voting/src/lib.rs).

Comment: Thank you very much for the update @Alex

If the use case is to vote on a proposal, so that, either accept or reject the proposal. Do you think election pallet is suitable in that use case?

Thanks once again for your time and suggestion

Comment: Personally I'd use the Democracy Pallet as a guide for that