# Modifying substrate-node-template for voting system use case

Tags: substrate-node-template, blockchain

As a major project for my college, we are trying to modify the `substrate node template` for the voting system use case. Can anyone guide us on what would be the most important modules, palettes, and areas in the documentation we should refer to in order to successfully modify the substrate node template for the election (government) voting system use case?

Comment: you can start by adding [pallet-democracy](https://marketplace.substrate.io/pallets/pallet-democracy/)

Comment: what kind of voting system are you talking about?

Comment: e voting system used by government to elect candidates for government elections

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify any pallet, you need to make a new pallet and write you election logic in it, refer the link on how build a custom pallet. https://docs.substrate.io/build/custom-pallets/

Comment: Actually, I am new to blockchain programming so I was looking to modify and use some existing libraries for implementing election logic rather than starting from scratch but I don't know which existing functions would be relevant for  election use case needed guidance for that

Comment: Blockchain election algorithm is totally different from governance election, but if you want to change it then go ahead

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look into this previous StackExchange question with a list of resources about voting on Substrate: [How to implement voting functionality?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8132/how-to-implement-voting-functionality)